# Forward error correction for for long strings of bits

Tags: strings, error-correcting-codes

Let $a$ be a large string of bits that is transmitted over a channel that introduces errors (insertions, deletions or substitutions) where the probability of an error happening is $p=0.01$ for each bit. Suppose also that each type of error has a probability of $1/3$ being chosen each time that an error is introduced to $a$. Let $b$ be the resulting string after transmission.

My question is: Is there a way to transmit $a$ correctly over the channel?

I've thought of using forward error correction, in particular I have considered adding redundancy, using *CRC*, or using something like *Reed–Solomon error correction*. However, I'd like to know if there is a simpler more naive way of doing this considering that $a$ and $b$ are just strings of $1$'s and $0$'s and that the probability of an error happening is relatively low.

Comment: See this answer on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/886757/1277.